# Reload Document into Google Docs Viewer (Clear Cache)

Tags: caching, google-docs, clear-cache

Google Docs Viewer (http://docs.google.com/viewer) creates a cache of a document after the first viewing. To see what I mean, try the following:

1. Upload `file.pdf` to your server (i.e., http://example.com).
2. Visit http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://example.com/file.pdf
3. Upload a new file to replace `file.pdf` (but use the same name).
4. Revisit http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://example.com/file.pdf.

Google Docs Viewer still shows the old `file.pdf`.

Anyone know how to correct this?

(I have already tried clearing browser cache, switching browsers, and logging in with a different google account to view the link.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears there is no way to clear the cache. Although, from my experience, Google tends to do it automatically about once a day.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you append a dynamic query string parameter to filename maybe cache will not work.

ex: http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://example.com/file.pdf?time=3454354

Comment: works only with the appended parameter, without there is no change

Answer (score 1):

I added `?time=0`

Seemed to work.